# oauth2 POST - twitter

Tags: python, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

i created a script that will get the users friend list (GET request) and i was successful. Now i am attempting to make a script that will follow a particular user (POST request) and i've been unsuccessful.

here is my oauth function (where the problem lies):

```
def augment_POST(url,**kwargs) :
    secrets = hidden.oauth()
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(secrets['consumer_key'], secrets['consumer_secret'])
    token = oauth2.Token(secrets['token_key'],secrets['token_secret'])

    oauth_request = oauth2.Request.from_consumer_and_token(consumer, token= token, http_method='POST', http_url=url, parameters=kwargs)
    oauth_request.to_postdata() # this returns post data, where should i put it?
    oauth_request.sign_request(oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), consumer, token)
    return oauth_request.to_url()
```

my augment_GET function is the exact same thing except http_mehtod='GET'

for clarity:

```
def follow_user(id):
    seedurl="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"
    print 'Attempting to follow: %d' % (id,)
    url = augment_POST(seedurl,user_id=id)
    connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = connection.read()
    headers = connection.info().dict
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should not be using oauth2 to make this request. What is this OAuth library?

Comment: Nevermind this library has a confusing name

Comment: I get an error 404 with your link

Comment: [documentation](https://oauth.net/2/)
*sorry about that.

Comment: it is not the documentation of your library, it's the OAuth2 protocol (which is not what you want if you want to follow an user on twitter)

Comment: But I found the source code of your library (or at least it looks like it is) [here](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/__init__.py) and I think you need to set the `is_form_encoded` argument to True when you create your request when you want to send a POST request

Comment: Oh no it's easier actually, you need to change `to_url` in `to_postdata` in the last line, or use the `to_header` method to send the OAuth parameters as headers (which works for both GET and POST requests)

Comment: to_postdata returns the serialized headers. I edited OP, take a look @odrling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it seems you need to `import urllib2` to make a POST request.
You have to send the POST data that you get from the `to_postdata` method
using the `data` argument of `urlopen`:

```
def augment_POST(url, **kwargs) :
    secrets = hidden.oauth()
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(secrets['consumer_key'],
                               secrets['consumer_secret'])
    token = oauth2.Token(secrets['token_key'],
                         secrets['token_secret'])

    oauth_request = oauth2.Request.from_consumer_and_token(
        consumer,
        token= token,
        http_method='POST',
        http_url=url,
        parameters=kwargs
    )

    oauth_request.sign_request(oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(),
                               consumer, token)

    # this is the data that must be sent with you POST request
    return oauth_request.to_postdata()


def follow_user(id):
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"
    print 'Attempting to follow: %d' % id
    postdata = augment(url, method='GET', user_id=id)

    # Send the POST request with the data argument
    # The url is the same as the data is sent in the body of the request
    connection = urllib2.urlopen(url, data=postdata)

    data = connection.read()
    headers = connection.info().dict
```

---

I would recommend to use the `requests_oauthlib` module which makes all this really easy:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

tokens = hidden.oauth()
client = OAuth1Session(tokens['consumer_key'],
                       tokens['consumer_secret'],
                       tokens['token_key'],
                       tokens['token_secret'])


def follow_user(id):
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"
    print 'Attempting to follow: %d' % id

    # for GET requests use client.get and the `params` argument
    # instead of the `data` argument
    response = client.post(url, data={'user_id': id})

    data = response.text
    # or even `data = response.json()` to decode the data
    headers = response.headers
```

Comment: thank you so much! can i contact you on another topic? getting the bearer token from twitter. i under stand the concept i just cant figure out how you implement it.

Comment: To get the bearer token you have to make a Basic Authorization header with your consumer key as username and your consumer secret as password. Then you send a POST request to https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token using the header you generated. You can use json to parse the response and get your bearer. Then you just put your bearer token in your authentication token in the format "Bearer {bearer_token}".